# How to resolve the error for "Alter Subscription disable"?

Tags: postgresql, replication, pg-logical

I have the following subscription for logical replication:

```
pctest1=> SELECT subscription_name, status FROM pglogical.show_subscription_status();
          subscription_name          |   status
-------------------------------------+-------------
         sandbox_rds_pg10_subscriber | replicating
(1 row)
```

When I try to disable this, it returns the below error:

```
pctest1=>  alter SUBSCRIPTION sandbox_rds_pg10_subscriber disable;
ERROR:  subscription "sandbox_rds_pg10_subscriber" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the below functions will work:

```
     pctest1=> select pglogical.alter_subscription_disable('sandbox_rds_pg10_subscriber');
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------+--
alter_subscription_disable | t

pctest1=> select * from pglogical.show_subscription_status();
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
subscription_name | sandbox_rds_pg10_subscriber
status            | disabled
provider_node     | sandbox_provider
provider_dsn      | host=10.xx.xx.xx port=xxxx dbname=sandbox_uat user=admin password=xxxxxxxxxx
slot_name         | pgl_pctest1_sand2c004cb_sand98307b9
replication_sets  | {default}
forward_origins   | {all}

pctest1=> select pglogical.alter_subscription_enable('sandbox_rds_pg10_subscriber');
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------------+--
alter_subscription_enable | t

pctest1=> select * from pglogical.show_subscription_status();
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
subscription_name | sandbox_rds_pg10_subscriber
status            | replicating
provider_node     | sandbox_provider
provider_dsn      | host=10.x.x.x port=xxxx dbname=sandbox_uat user=admin password=xxxxxxxx
slot_name         | pgl_pctest1_sand2c004cb_sand98307b9
replication_sets  | {default}
forward_origins   | {all}
```

Comment: It would have been helpful if the question had mentioned that you are using a third-party replication tool.